# Как исправить ошибку в Chrome 88 с неправильным определением часового пояса

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Начиная примерно с 20.01.2021, после обновления Chrome, в приложениях стал некорректно обрабатываться часовой пояс. При вызове функции Date() оказалось, что у пояса отличается знак (-07:00 вместо +07:00):

[image: Часовой пояс -7]

Системное время установлено корректно:

[image: Системный часовой пояс +7]

При изменении часового пояса в системе и перезапуске браузера, часовой пояс подхватывается корректно. После перезагрузки операционной системы проблема возвращается. Проблема наблюдается на Windows 7 и Windows 10. В браузере Mozilla Firefox такой ошибки нет.

Версия Chrome в которой ошибка продолжает оставаться:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, столкнулся ли кто-нибудь с такой же проблемой и как её решить?

Comment: У меня Windows 10, такая же как и у вас версия хрома - часовой пояс определяется нормально. Может, у вас стоит какая-то софтина, которая меняет время?

Comment: Аналогично.
Те же симптомы, та же сборка.
Вероятно, дело в последнем обновлении браузера от 20.01.2021
Что делать - ХЗ, ждать след обновления (

Comment: @Сергей, а операционная система у вас какая?

Comment: Проблема уже обсуждается в [трекере Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1168528)

Comment: Держите нас в курсе

Answer (score 1):

Операционка Win7.
Кстати вот еще: "Здравствуйте все! Спасибо за сообщения и ожидание решения. Проблема передана в команду продукта Хром, и исследуется для решения, трекномер для отслеживания в команде и упоминания для пользователей : 1168528" Это отсюда: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/94274830?hl=ru

Answer (score 1):

Можно вылечить следующими действиями:

1. Открываем настройки даты и времени
2. Меняем таймзону на любую другую, сохраняем.
3. Возвращаем родную таймзону, сохраняем

В результат в браузере дата начинает работать корректно

Comment: ну, такое. Только для личного пользования. Пользователи точно не будут это делать

Comment: после перезагрузки всё слетает